# D - Set default value for a struct member which is a multidimensional static array

Tags: multidimensional-array, initialization, d, dmd, member-initialization

I am using the D programming language.
I want to have a `struct` containing a multidimensional static array of `int`s initially filled with a non-zero value (in my case, zero is a valid entry, and I want to initially mark all entries as invalid).
As it is a `struct`, it can not have a default constructor.
Instead, I can supply a default value for the member of the `struct`.

The question is: how do I write this multidimensional array value in a short and readable way? Is there any convenience function, special-case syntax or idiom to do that?

---

Here is what I came up with.

```
import std.range;
import std.stdio;

struct S
{
    static immutable int SIZE =  3;
    static immutable int NA   = -1;

    int [SIZE] [SIZE] a = NA.repeat(SIZE).array().repeat(SIZE).array();
}

void main()
{
    S s;
    writeln(s);
}
```

This prints the array of `-1`s as expected:

```
S([[-1, -1, -1], [-1, -1, -1], [-1, -1, -1]])
```

Still, the expression `NA.repeat(SIZE).array().repeat(SIZE).array()` looks lengthy, and I suspect there could be a better (more idiomatic, more readable) way to express my intent.

---

**Update** with a few more attempts:

1. `int [SIZE] [SIZE] a = NA;` does not compile, even with the current beta: dmd-2.066-b2.
2. `int [SIZE] [SIZE] a = NA.repeat (SIZE).array ();` compiles and does the thing.
   Still, the consistency suffers.
3. `int [SIZE] [SIZE] a = [NA, NA, NA];` looks like it is essentially the above expression, simplified.
   It compiles but fills only the first three-element subarray with `NA`s.
   The other two subarrays contain some garbage-like stuff.
   Is that a partial initialization feature of some kind?
   To me, it looks more like a bug, like, compiler accepting invalid code.
4. `int [SIZE] [SIZE] a = [NA];` sets the first subarray to `[-1, 0, 0]` and the rest to the same garbage as the previous attempt.
5. There is also `fill` in `std.algorithm`, but it works for ranges (not ranges of ranges), and does not look like it's readily usable in an initializer.
   At least it won't be shorter.

Comment: huh, for a single dimensional array, you can just set it to an integer. For a multidim static array it seems to me that maybe the same thing should work, since they are really the same memory wise. of course this is a compiler enhancement rather than a real answer. tbh i'd just take your long line and make a function out of it so it is mroe readable at the usage point and call it done.

Comment: If I remember well, there were talks about improving the static array initialization to allow something like `int[100][100] arr = 40;`. Try the new 2.066b1, maybe it is there.

Comment: @Adam: you mean a recursive template specialized for array and non-array elements? That's a nice idea, but still a bit overkill for such a simple task, don't you think?

Comment: @DejanLekic: tried with 2.066b2, not working. See the update in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about something like this:

```
module main;
import std.stdio: writeln;

enum SIZE =  3;
enum NA = -1;

struct Int {
    int v = -1;
    alias v this;
}

struct S
{
    Int [SIZE] [SIZE] a;
}

void main()
{
    S s;
    writeln(s);
}
```

Comment: That looks nice, thank you!  And with a simple benchmark, `dmd -O -release -inline -noboundscheck` produces the exact same assembly.  So, optimization opportunities for that `Int` struct are comparable to a simple `int`, which can also be important.

Comment: ("The exact same assembly" refers to further usage, not initialization, of the struct.)